# Как сравнить две неравные массивы

Tags: javascript

У нас есть например две массивы как сравнить его одним циклом? и так чтобы вместо того чтобы выдать ошибку написал что ни-будь.. ошибку выдает тогда когда один массив меньше другого.
нужно сравнить независимой длиной, всмысле так, если первый массив длинее второго, то второй заполняется до первого например цифрой 0

```
let x = [5,123,21,2312,3,4,1234]
let y = [1234,45,34,12,123]
```

Comment: сравнить только на длину? непонятно

Comment: критерий равенства толком опишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let x = [5,123,21,2312,3,4,1234];
let y = [1234,45,34,12,123];

let lengthDiff = Math.abs(x.length - y.length);
let zeroArr = Array(lengthDiff).fill(0);  
  
if (x.length > y.length) {
  y = y.concat(zeroArr);
} else {
  x = x.concat(zeroArr);
}
  

console.log(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробую пованговать

```js
let a = [5,123,21,2312,3,4,1234]
let b = [1234,45,34,12,123]

for(let i=0; i< Math.min(a.length,b.length); i++){
  if (a[i]< b[i]){
    console.log(a[i]+" < " + b[i]);
  } else{
    console.log(a[i]+" > " + b[i]);
  }
}
```